# How to pass int from IEnumerable<int> to custom Enum Validator?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have made a custom enum validator to check if int from IEnumerable is part of Enum

```
public class CustomEnumValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<int>
where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public CustomEnumValidator(int value)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value must be part of enum");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this works yet because I have a problem passing the int value to the custom validator

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Values) //Values is IEnumerable<int>
    .SetValidator(new CustomEnumValidator<CustomEnumValues>(x))//this line is throwing error
    .When(x => x.Values.Any());
```

So how do I pass the each int value to the CustomEnumValidator, and is my validator correct?

Comment: I wonder why you throw an exception IF the value is really defined?=!

Comment: Looking at the documentation you don't give the value(s) to be validated via a constructor. That will be handled via the SetValidator call and the base class for  the validator. You just need to define a rule in the validators constructor that iterates over all values. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I personaly would propaply not do it that way, for multiple reasons, but if you need to do it that way, why not pass the value like this?

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
      new CustomEnumValidator<TestEnum>(item);
}
```

Edit:
Other Version in LINQ:

```
list.Where(item =>
        {
            new CustomEnumValidator<TestEnum>(item);
            return true;
        })
```

Comment: We kind of wanted it to fit the fluentvalidation and use a genericcustomvalidator as it would be used by many times

Comment: Add edited an other variant into the awnser. Does that work better for you?

Comment: how do i integrate it with fluent validation to use RuleForEach(x => x.Values)...

Comment: okey. I dont use fluent validation but that here looks manageable: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html  

maybe that helps.